# ctypedef a cython function with default arguments

Tags: cython

I have a cython function like:

```
cdef void foo(int a, int b=1, int c=2):
    pass
```

and a getter function to return its address:

```
def get_foo():
    return <size_t>foo
```

so I can get function `foo`'s address somewhere and cast it back to the real function in cython(eg: a callback one can use in python).

The problem is how to write such a type?

I tried:

```
cdef void foo(int a, int b=1, int c=2):
    pass
ctypedef void (*foo_type)(int a, int b, int c)
cdef foo_type f = foo
```

this won't compile, cython complains: Cannot assign type 'void (int, struct __pyx_opt_args_46_cython_magic_49f265438c694830523a60bef4fe2ee8_foo *__pyx_optional_args)' to 'foo_type '

From the error mesage , one can note that, the option(default) arguments are wrapped in a struct by cython.

Is there a way to do such ctypedef in cython? If not, I think I'd better leave out the default value.:-(

Answer (score 0):

You can create small wrappers without the default values:

```
cdef void foo_abc(int a, int b, int c):
    foo(a,b,c)

# if you need it
cdef void foo_ab(int a, int b):
    foo(a,b)
# etc
```

These will be convertable to function pointers:

```
cdef foo_type f = foo_abc
```

The speed loss from the wrapper functions will be small, so the main cost is just that you need to write a bit more code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a possible way. Finally I figured out default argument cannot be provided for function pointers and default arguments are not taken into consideration for the type, it's really a question for the c/c++ part. I have a function with many parameters, much of them have a default value for convenience, adding so many wrappers will be dull, so leaving out the default value in the c/cython part and leaving it for the python part will be better for me, after all, its a python extension:-D